# String overlaps next column with jspdf-autotable and overflow linebreak

Tags: jspdf, jspdf-autotable

I'm using jspdf-autoTable with the option `overflow: 'linebreak'` to create a pdf. The problem is that some long texts are overlapping the next column. For example, if my text is "Hai hello welcome" it will print as "Hai hello wel" with the remaining "come" overlapped on the next column. How can I use linebreak without overlapping the next column?

**Note:** Linebreak works fine until I'm changing the text in the `drawCell method`.

I get this weird behavior as well:

**What I send in:**

```
Paragraph writing is the foundation of all essay writing whether the form is expository persuasive narrative or creative
```

**Inside my drawCell method:**

```
["Paragraph writing is the foundation of all","essay writing whether the form is expository","persuasive narrative or creative"]
```

I don't know why it automatically divided the string into an array. Could this be the reason for the overlapping issue?

Comment: Me to facing same kind of issue's . Waiting for the Solution

Answer (score 1):

It is expected that the string turns into an array. The jspdf lib will print each string in the array on a new line. If you want to change the string with hooks, use the `didParseCell`.

Comment: _The jspdf lib will print each string in the array on a new line_ .Ok fine , Let me ask two question here . **1.** Is it possible to increase or decrease the length of the string which is separated by `drawCell` ?   **2.** If that one is not possible mean's how can i customize the  words print in every column or how can I know a column of pdf contain maximum char . like i have a column which is having width of  250 . let me ask how many chars accepted in the column of every line.

Comment: Based upon what drawCell splitting the string with comma(,) ?

Comment: It fits the texts inside each cell with doc.splitTextToSize(str, width). You can customize the lengths of the strings by either increasing or decreasing the column widths. You can disable the string splittring by using `tableWidth: 'wrap';`.

Comment: @SimonBengtsson If I am using the  `createdCell` How do I know the maximum words or char occupied in every row for a particular column .., Because the `createdCell` gave the text as its same .. How do I chop the words in the row correctly I am struggling How to chop the words in every sentence correctly for every row. I am facing an Problem like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38974060/some-words-are-hide-at-the-end-of-column-using-jspdf-autotable

Comment: You don't know the maxium words or chars before it is calculated by jspdf's function `doc.splitTextToSize`. An I takes less width than a O for example.